# applying git patch will automatically add patch files for staging?

Tags: git

I applied a patch to my master branch. I do a git status and I can see that the files already show up under "Changes to be committed:". 
So does applying git patch automatically add patch files for staging? If so, why?

Comment: From what I read on the help page, git apply can do it on files (working tree.... or even without it) or also to the index (with `--index`).

Answer (score 2):

Here is how `git apply` works, according to the doc and to what I can see in my repos :

- `git apply path/to/patch` apply patch only in the working tree, so you have to add then commit the changes
- `git apply --index path/to/patch` apply patch to the working tree and the index, so you just have to commit the changes
- `git apply --cached path/to/patch` apply patch only in the index so you just have to commit the changes

This is true since the first versions of git so what you see is very strange. Do you by any chance have an alias that could look like `alias.apply -> 'apply --index'` ?